# Honeycomb and TabHost specs

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have a question about Honeycomb's backward compatibility.  I have an app that supports 2.1 or higher and seems to mostly work on Honeycomb except when they start a TabActivity.

In particular, when I add tabs to the TabHost, I get the following exception

android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

When looking at the code that throws this exception, I see that it's the tab spec that has a label and an icon.  Inside the code, in the LabelAndIconIndicatorStrategy tries to inflate             the layout file R.layout.tab_indicator which doesn't appear to be available.

```
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(_gameActivity, ScoreGameActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(GameChangerConstants.STREAM_ID, _stream.pk().toString());

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = _gameTabHost.newTabSpec("score_game").setIndicator("Score", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_field_gloss)).setContent(intent);
    _gameTabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Is there a new way of creating tabs for honeycomb that I don't know about?  I've poured over the documentation but haven't seen anything that indicates a problem with what I've done.

I'd like to avoid having to use fragments at this point until we can do a more comprehensive restructuring of our UI widgets and I'd like to better understand this issue.

Comment: Post your logcat for the exception. I had to deal with a problem recently between v2.1 and up which was TabActivity related. It may not be the same but it's worth a look.

Comment: Tabs work fine on Honeycomb. These sample projects all work fine on a XOOM: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/Tab https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Fancy/DynamicTab https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Activities/IntentTab

Comment: @MisterSquonk  wasn't quite sure how much you wanted to see so here's the link to a pastie [link]http://pastie.org/1704756[/link]

Comment: @CommonsWare - I just tried with just a label and get the same error.  I'm not using the layout xml files but creating everything programmatically so I'm thinking this is where the problem may lie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe I've found a solution, but because people are curious, here is the stacktrace I got when I ran into this problem:

```
05-17 13:09:53.462: ERROR/CustomExceptionHandler(500): Uncaught throwable in thread Thread[main,5,main]
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1014)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2039)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:853)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:389)
    at android.widget.TabHost$LabelAndIconIndicatorStrategy.createIndicatorView(TabHost.java:568)
    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:226)
    at com.myApp.ui.TabDialog.addTab(TabDialog.java:80)
    ...
```

At that line, I have code roughly equivalent to what sparky saw:

```
spec = myTabHost.newTabSpec("score_game").setIndicator("Score", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_field_gloss)).setContent(intent);
myTabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Note that `myTabHost` is a TabHost and `spec` is a TabSpec.

Previously, I was initializing `myTabHost` like this:

```
//WRONG - This can CRASH your app starting at Android SDK 3.0
TabHost myTabHost = new TabHost(getContext());
```

To fix this problem, I started initializing the TabHost by doing this:

```
TabHost myTabHost = new TabHost(getContext(), null);
```

And that fixed it! I would love to find a root cause, but I haven't yet been able to figure it out.

Comment: thanks unchek.  I actually just went ahead and moved all the tab host initialization into the xml layout resource which seems to have resolved the issue, but it's good to know that there's a solution.

Comment: @plowman thank you. This fixes my problem by calling the constructor with null for the AttributeSet. Regarding your question, the reason is that the single param constructor is not calling this( context, null, com.android.internal.R.attr.tabWidgetStyle ), instead it calls super( ctx), hence many things are no initialized that are needed on the TabHost